# Pros and cons of removing htaccess file for apache performance?

Tags: performance, apache, .htaccess

I want to know if there is any significant gain over performance in Apache if we remove the htaccess files from our code and simply put all the redirect rules(which are currently in htaccess files) directly into the server config?

I have been through various posts and some say that the performance would be better. I want to know what are the pros and cons of both the approaches.

I have noted down following, please add your inputs to the list.

**Pros:**

1) Performance improvement.

**Cons:**

1) Server would be required to restart every time we change any of the rule.

Comment: once important info link: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: *"you should only use .htaccess files when you don't have access to the main server configuration file"*

Comment: Yea @arthur, I read this line from apache docs, but there are cons as well like the one I said above. Before simply removing all the htaccess files from my project and moving ALL the redirect rules directly in server conf, I just want to analyze if its worth a do.